# std::apply and constant expression?

Tags: c++, c++17, stdapply

I tried code below in [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Cz6H2yv3vq0jHngn):

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>


int main()
{
    constexpr std::array<const char, 10> str{"123456789"};
    constexpr auto foo = std::apply([](auto... args) constexpr { std::integer_sequence<char, args...>{}; } , str);
    std::cout << typeid(foo).name();
}
```

and the compiler told me that `args...` are not constant expression.
What's wrong?

Comment: Unless this has changed in C++1z, you cannot have constexpr function parameters. That is, every function must assume it may be called with runtime parameters, and then your lambda doesn't make sense.

Comment: @krzaq What a pity…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All constexpr functions must be valid both constexpr and not, even if marked constexpr.

There is a proposal for a constexpr literal that passed characters as non type template parameters.  Then `"hello"_bob` could expand directly to a parameter pack.

Another approach is you can pass `std::integral_constant<T, t>` to the lambda through some mechanism, like my `indexer`.  Then converting to `T` is constexpr even tho the variable is not.  This does not help you with `"hello"` to a sequence.

Answer (score 7):

Function parameters cannot be labeled `constexpr`. As such, you cannot use them in places that require constant expressions, like non-type template arguments.

To do the kind of thing you're trying to do would require some kind of compile-time string processing, based around template arguments.

Answer (score 5):

What you want can be done without `std::apply`:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template <std::size_t N, class = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
struct iterate;

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
struct iterate<N, std::index_sequence<Is...>> {
    template <class Lambda>
    constexpr auto operator()(Lambda lambda) {
        return lambda(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>{}...);
    }
};

int main()
{
    constexpr std::array<const char, 10> str{"123456789"};
    constexpr auto foo = iterate<str.size()>{}([](auto... is) constexpr { return std::integer_sequence<char, str[is]...>{}; });
    std::cout << typeid(foo).name();
}
```

[[live demo]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Fu9gybD2CrIRYDTm)

Comment: I actually now think it shouldn't but not sure yet... :/

Comment: I'm more concerned about using arguments in a constant expression. As per the other answers I'd have expected it to ensure this is also callable with runtime arguments.

Comment: Though I don't have such doubts with [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/jjmSjmwHlZ8rec5L) code. It's a clever idea!

Comment: I think this one is actually ok. `std::integral_constant` has its overload of `constexpr operator T()` allowing it to be used in constexpr context. Or am I mising something?

Comment: The question if `str` declared in `main` can be used in context of lambda is on the other hand still opened..

Comment: You seem to be right about integral constants. http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#10  and http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#13 suggest that your code is perfectly okay

Comment: Nice founding! Thank you!

Comment: You can even make "factory" for it, but currently gcc crashed on this http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/JRvLX98vakSP1k2k .

Comment: @Orient Nice test for compiler you've made... Have you watched what syntax element caused compiler crash was it constexpr lambda or auto template parameter...?

Comment: Namely `auto const &` template parameter. If it slightly modified to be `template< std::size_t size, char const (& value)[size] >`, then all is OK, but then I need to provide `size` parameter manually.

Comment: @Orient one word - I've just noticed you used gcc clang extension on string literal, while I'm opened on that, some people would probably like to wait for when it become official c++ feature...

Comment: @W.F. I submitted the bug, but it's status is not changed yet to resolved. That extension is quite old. Don't know is there a proposal for it.

Comment: @W.F. Which wandbox compiled fine? [This](http://melpon.org/wandbox/) still can't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127990/discussion-between-w-f-and-orient).